# Convert Arduino checksum-function to C#

Tags: c#, c++, arduino, checksum

I've got this Arduino-checksum function I'd like to use in C# to check the validity of the data I received:

`char`s in Arduino are 1 byte long, `int`s take two bytes, the corresponding data-type in C# is `short`

```
char Send::calcChecksum(const char* const packet, const int packetLength) {
    int i = 0;
    char checksum = 0;
    while(i < packetLength) {
        checksum ^= packet[i++];
    }
    return checksum;
}
```

**How would I write this function in C# ?** I'm especially confused what the `^=` operator does.

Comment: "a ^= b" means "a = a XOR b"

Comment: like @user2950911 says, it is a XOR Assignment and it is exactly the same in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var stringToCheck = "hi there";

        Console.WriteLine("Checksum for " + stringToCheck + ": " + CalcChecksum(stringToCheck, stringToCheck.Length));
    }

    static int CalcChecksum(string packet, int packetLength)
    {
        char checksum = (char)0;

        for (int i = 0; i < packetLength; i++)
        {
            checksum ^= packet[i];
        }

        return checksum;
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/6icpvv